# Vue dynamic import with different URL

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to dynamic import components on my app, what i'm doing:

```
const app = new Vue({
    vuetify,
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'MainComponent': () => import(
          /* webpackChunkName: "components/js/MainPage/MainComponent" */ 
          './components/MainPage/MainComponent.vue'
        ),
        'OnlineReservationComponent': () => import(
          /* webpackChunkName: "components/js/MainPage/OnlineReservationComponent" */ 
          './components/MainPage/OnlineReservationComponent.vue'
        ),
    }
});
```

When i load the page it i get an error that the file is not found,

```
GET https://domain.test/components/js/MainPage/MainComponent.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

that's because the file must be inside core folder

the folder structure

```
core
--public
---components
----js
-----mainPage
```

Is there any way to make webpack look inside the Core folder like this

```
https://domain.test/core/public/components/js/MainPage/MainComponent.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing inside webpack.mix.js

```
mix.webpackConfig({
     output: {
        publicPath: '/core/public/'
     }
  })
```

Fixed my problem